# Deserialization of incoming message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Json is sent from the client to my api controller

**Message**

```
{"todo":{"title":"jo","isCompleted":false,"isDeleted":false,"testFK":null}}
```

I will list different consuming server side methods that should receive this message transformed into a object

```
public void Post(TaskEntity todo)
{
    using (var context = new ToDoEntities())
    {
        context.Tasks.Add(todo.ToEf());
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

`todo` parameter is null.

```
public void Post(UpdateTodoInputMessage message)
{
    using (var context = new ToDoEntities())
    {
        context.Tasks.Add(todo.todo.ToEf());
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Message class**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Messages
{
    [DataContract]
    public class UpdateTodoInputMessage
    {
        [DataMember]
        public TaskEntity todo { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

The `todo` property of the message class is null.

If I change the post method to a string then my client receives a *405 Method not allowed*.

```
public void Post(string message)
{
    using (var context = new ToDoEntities())
    {
       // context.Tasks.Add(todo.todo.ToEf());
       // context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I am at a loss and would love some assistance as to how the deserialization of the string is taking place, and why I am getting these strange results.

Comment: found the problem needed a empty constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that my Task Entity class didn't have a empty constructor